# Regression Neural Network with NumPy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I want to make regression neural network with `Python` and `Numpy`. I have made one for classification, where I used `sigmoid` function, but I do not know how to change my function into regression.
I know that linear function should look like `y=k*x + n`, but I do not know how to represent that In python. What is my `n` and `k` values, how to pass them to my function?

Ofc, I put simple linear function, but My goal is to create something like`RBF` function.

This is the code that I have, but in his code I have sigmoid function, and I want to have regression function.

How can I change sigmoid function with regression function and its derivate function?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'input 1':[0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.4, -0.4, 0.4, 0.1, -0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0, 0.4, -0.2, -0.4],
                   'input 2':[0.3, 0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.9, 0, 0.35, -0.4, -0.9, 0.4, 0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'input 3':[0, 0.4, 0, -0.1, 0.4, -0.2, 0.7, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.5, 0.4, -0.31, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2],
                   'result':[21, 31, 10, 6, 53, 31, 13, 15,16, 15, 26, 36, 52, 41, 14, 8, 14, 13, 11, 4]})

print(df)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivate(x):
    return x * (1 - x)


features = df.iloc[:,:-1].to_numpy()
results =  df.iloc[:,-1:].to_numpy()

np.random.seed(1)

weights = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

print('These are my random weights:\n')
print(weights)

for iteration in range(100000):

    input_layer = features

    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, weights))
    error = results - outputs
    adjustments = error * sigmoid_derivate(outputs)
    weights += np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustments)


df['output prediction'] = outputs.round(0)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented a classification system that using the sigmoid will yield values between 0 and 1.

For linear regression type of problem, you can simply create the Output layer without any activation function as we are interested in numerical values without any transformation.

So actually to predict the values, you just need a linear regression model.

---

**Small example for a  linear regression model optimized with gradient descend.**

```
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].to_numpy()
y =  df.iloc[:,-1:].to_numpy()

def compute_cost(X, y, params):
    n_samples = len(y)
    h = X @ params  # dot product
    return (1/(2*n_samples))*np.sum((h-y)**2)

def gradient_descent(X, y, params, learning_rate, n_iters):
    n_samples = len(y)
    J_history = np.zeros((n_iters,1))

    for i in range(n_iters):
        params = params - (learning_rate/n_samples) * X.T @ (X @ params - y) 
        J_history[i] = compute_cost(X, y, params)

    return (J_history, params)

n_samples = len(y)
mu = np.mean(X, 0)
sigma = np.std(X, 0)

X = (X-mu) / sigma # normalize

X = np.hstack((np.ones((n_samples,1)),X))  # add bias term
n_features = np.size(X,1)

params = np.zeros((n_features,1))  # initial guess

n_iters = 1500
learning_rate = 0.01

initial_cost = compute_cost(X, y, params)

print("Initial cost is: ", initial_cost, "\n")

(J_history, optimal_params) = gradient_descent(X, y, params, learning_rate, n_iters)

print("Optimal parameters are: \n", optimal_params, "\n")

print("Final cost is: ", J_history[-1])

plt.plot(range(len(J_history)), J_history, 'r')

plt.title("Convergence Graph of Cost Function")
plt.xlabel("Number of Iterations")
plt.ylabel("Cost")
plt.show()
```

**Keep in mind that OLS can be expressed in a matrix close form and thus, the gradient descend will not be needed.**

Comment: Im aware of that, but i do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revise your understanding of the function of neural network. Indeed , you shoould initialize your network by a sequential ,then you should add
an input layer which should contain the number of features in the data that you will use . Besides you should add the hidden layers that you will use and you finish by add the output layer in which you should mention that the number of output is 1 and the activation function is 'linear'.
I give you an exemple

## Initialize network

NN=Sequential()

## Input layer

NN.add(Dense(N0,input_dim=features.shape[1],activation='relu')

## Hidden layers

NN.add(Dense(N1, activation='relu'))
NN.add(Dense(N2,activation='relu'))
.
.
.
.

## Output layer

NN.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))

Comment: I do not understand the code that you posted. Is it possible to implement your solution to my code?